# If $f$ is differentiable then $\mathrm{int}(f(U))=\varnothing$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:U\subset\mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a differentiable function where $m<n$ and $U$ an open set.

How to prove that $$\mathrm{int}(f(U))=\varnothing$$

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: You can show that $f(U)$ is a Lebesgue null set, hence it has empty interior, if you can use some measure theory.